# Name function in XPATH

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following elements in my xmi file:

```
<element1 id= 3 >

<element2 id= 3>
```

I want to transform them into something like:

```
<element1 id= 3 name =element2>
<element2 id= 3>
```

I am using xslt to transform:

```
<xsl:if test="@id = //*[@id]/@id">
                <xsl:sequence
                    select="fn:createAtt('name',X)" />
            </xsl:if>
```

I want to compare the id of two elements and in case they match then i want to save the name of second element (element2) into the name attribute of first element.

The comparison works ok. The problem is how to read the name of the second element ? I tried to use the name() function but am not able to read exactly that name that matches the comparison.

Comment: I found the name function. I tried to use into the following way:name(//*[@id=@id]) and it returns null but if i use name(//*[@id=3]) then it returns the element2. How can i do this automatically  by using the name id of the first element rather than a static value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this: first define a key as

```
<xsl:key name="el-by-id" match="*" use="@id"/>
```

then I would write a template

```
<xsl:template match="*[@id]">
  <xsl:variable name="same-id" use="key('el-by-id', @id) except ."/>
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
     <xsl:if test="$same-id">
       <xsl:attribute name="name" select="node-name($same-id[1])"/>
     </xsl:if>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

That way you can efficiently reference the elements using a key, then if one element of the same id is found the attribute named `name` is created. I used the XSLT/XPath 2.0 `node-name` function, depending on your exact requirements you might want to use `<xsl:attribute name="name" select="name($same-id[1])"/>` instead.

Comment: Isn't there a way to just read the second id of the second element and compare it inside the name function. Which means that there where i am using the fix number in the function name(//*[@id=3]) to use the id of the second element ? If i can manage to do it then my problem is solved. thank you for your help

Comment: Depending on the context you might want `name((//*[@id = current()/@id] except current())[1])`.